# Look up and return line below Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to create a "search" to go through a Google Sheet. There are technically two searches. The first one works as it should but the second has issues. Basically, I need the return of two values. So if I type "E" as the search key I need it to return 1 & 2. So far I can get it to pull 1 and thought I could use the return cell as the new search key. But it tells me it can't find 1.

For reference I used `=VLOOKUP(A2,B5:C12,2,False)` for 1st parameter and `=HLOOKUP(B2,C5:C12,2,False)` as second.

Image is obviously not the sheet I'm using but testing on a smaller scale.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=filter(C5:C12,ArrayFormula(if(row(B5:B12)<=MATCH(2,1/(C:C<>""),1),lookup(row(C5:C),row(C5:C)/if(B5:B12<>"",TRUE,FALSE),B5:B12),))=A2)`

---

---

**Sample**
[image: sample]